# Sequence in a hilbert space.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, self-learning

$M$ is a closed subspace of the Hilbert space $H$, and x $\in H$.

Call $d = \inf_{y \in M} ||x - y||^2$

Show that there exist a sequence of elements $y_n$ of M such that $||y_n - x ||^2 \rightarrow d$ .

So I would like to prove that there exists a sequence of $y_n$ s.t.

$$||y_n||^2 - 2\langle x,y_n\rangle + ||x|| \rightarrow d $$

Comment: Isn't that simply the definition of the infimum? I think you rather want to show the existence of an element $y\in M$ such that the inf is achieved, i.e. $d=\| x-y\|$. To this end, the definition of inf/convergence and the parallelogram identity might help.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks I edited the post

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 I think here lies my problem, the only def of infimum I know is : the biggest real number that is smaller or equal to every number in a certain set. How do I recover the equivalence with this sequential definition?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 What I want to prove is that such a sequence that has as limit $d$ exists, if it was: there exist a sequence $y_n \rightarrow d$ I would have no problem because a closed set contains all it's limit points, but I am not sure about $||y - x ||^2 \rightarrow d$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution of your problem is an easy application of the proposition below:

**Theorem:** Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $A$ is bounded below. Then there is a $m\in\mathbb{R}$ such that

1. $m$ is a lower bound for $A$ and
2. given any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $m\leq a<m+\epsilon$

If $d=\inf_{y\in M} \|x-y\|^2$ then for $\epsilon=1$ there must be a $y_1\in M$ such that $d\leq\|x-y_1\|^2<d+1$ and for $\epsilon=1/2$ there must be a $y_2\in M$ such that $d\leq\|x-y_2\|^2<d+1/2$ and continue in this fashion. The sequence $(y_n)$ satisfies the desired convergence.

Comment: So the closed subspace is bounded because it is a complete vector space? where does the boundedness come from?  Thanks for the very nice answer.

Comment: Subspaces of vector spaces are always unbounded no matter the subspace is closed or not. Even if a subspace is not closed still you can construct a sequence satisfying the desired convergence. But closedness guarantees an element of $y_0\in M$ such that $d=\|x-y_0\|$.

Comment: closedness guarantees the existence of an infimum? I am having troubles thinking of an unbounded set with an infimum.

Comment: You are not calculating the infimum of elements of $M$. To talk about the infimum of a subset (or subspace) of a vector space (or Banach or Hilbert space), the space must be partially ordered set. Consider the function $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(y)=\|x-y\|^2$ for $y\in M$. $f(M)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ so it is the infimum of $f(M)$, the subset of $\mathbb{R}$. For example $f(M)$ can be $[5,\infty)$. It is unbounded set bu its infimum is 5.

Comment: Ok, I think I am close but what guarantees that $f(M)$ is not $(-\infty,+\infty)$ ? Then I would not have an infimum.

Comment: Norm function cannot be negative so the set $f(M)$ is always bounded below and this guarantees the infimum.